# 401 Unauthorized error with AWS Api Gateway and Basic Authorizer for GET methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am getting 401 Unauthorized error with AWS Api Gateway and Basic Authorizer for GET methods.

The strange things seems to be that everything works if I change the method to POST.

Also an isolated test of the Authorizer works fine when using the AWS console.

It seems that the custom basic auth authorizer lambda is never called for the GET invocation.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, Cloudfront is in front of the API as a frontend/backend proxy. And if you test the GET request via the original API gateway DNS name, everything works as expected. So something happens in cloudfront :)

I have found the solution in this great medium post.

https://dev.to/dvddpl/basic-auth-on-lambda-api-gateway-cloudfront-solving-the-401-unauthorized-error-hif

He found out that for GET requests Cloudfront removes the Authorization header field before forwarding the request to the origin.

The solution is to add the Authorization header to the whitelist of the caching behaviour.

Check the medium POST for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you, and I just finally figured it out. The root cause is the generated authorizer response.

```
    response = {
      principalId: verifyTokenResponse.email,
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Resource: event.methodArn, // the issue is here
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

The format of `event.methodArn` is:

`arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:1234567890:3uiffepkxj/qa/PUT/book/completed`

You need to change that methodArn to be:

`arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:1234567890:3uiffepkxj/*`

Then it all works.